# How Can I Reduce Lag While Reading Serial Data From Arduino in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, adafruit

I'm reading data from an Inertial Measurement Unit in Arduino and Passing it to Python via Serial. Why do I have 8-10 seconds lag between any change in the Accelerometer axes and the output of my Python program?

Here is an Example:

Arduino:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>

#define BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS (100)
 
Adafruit_BNO055 myIMU = Adafruit_BNO055();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myIMU.begin();
  delay(1000);
  myIMU.setExtCrystalUse(true);

}

void loop() {
  //Get ACC vectors, x,y,z:
  imu::Vector<3> acc =myIMU.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_ACCELEROMETER);

  Serial.print(acc.x());
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(acc.y());
  delay(50);

}
```

Python:

```
import serial
import time
arduinoData=serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.usbmodemFD121', baudrate=115200)
time.sleep(1)
print ("hello")
while (1==1):
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass

    dataPacket=arduinoData.readline()

    dataPacket=str(dataPacket,'utf-8')
    splitPacket=dataPacket.split(',')
    accX=float(splitPacket[0])
    accY=float(splitPacket[1])
    print("Acc X=",accX,"Acc Y=",accY)
```

**Edit:**
I noticed the lag in the python program increases exponentially as the program runs, so after running 30-40 secs, the lag will be around 1.5 mins.

**Second edit:**
If I print the serial data without sorting it into a string the latency issue disappear.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about that mess. I have rephrased the question and edited the code to its bare minimum. I hope this is adequate, if not I'll find a more novice-friendly forum.

Comment: A point of observation, you are using readline to access your arduino data.  How long does it take to create the line of data?

Comment: It only takes a fraction of a second.  I get approximately 10 lines of data pr second.

Comment: I am assuming, when you say it only takes a fraction of a second, this based on observation of arduino output, am I correct?  If this is the case, is the aduino data being generated on the order of 6 to 8 characters?

Comment: I misunderstood. In the Arduino IDE serial monitor I'm getting 20 lines of data pr second and the reaction time between change in the accelerometer and serial monitor is more or less instantaneous. I get approximately 10 lines of data pr second from the python program. The data being sent from Arduino is a pair (x & y axes) of two decimal point integers between -9.80 and 9.80

Comment: Is there more to your python program  that would cause the delay to increase?  While I can't account for an increasing delay, I did wonder about your readline call.  If the transmission over the serial line was dropping the eol char, it could be the readline is waiting until it has a "full line" whatever that might be defined as to return the line.  You might want to examine the readline format to determine if other conditions can be controlled.

Comment: No, that's the whole program. I think you're on to something, when I print the readline call without sorting it into to a string, there are no delay issues, and the EOL chars are also printed. Could this be an encoding problem?

Comment: I truly don't know.  I haven't used the serial module, so am unfamiliar with its idiosyncrasies.

Comment: I remember having similar issue I did the decoding in 1 line as follow ```dataPacket=arduinoData.readline().decode('utf-8')``` Then after reading to flush the buffer 
           ```arduinoData.in_waiting```

Comment: @Fadi Abu Raid I get the same result.

Comment: Your problem is due to buffer filling faster than I your program can read thus you have to flush the buffer. I used arduinoData.in_waiting and it has the same effect. Maybe try arduinoData.reset_input_buffer().

Comment: @Fadi Abu Raid Now it works with no delay. I kept getting a _Value Error: could not convert string to float_ after 5-10 seconds. This error went away when I reverted to using `dataPacket=arduinoData.readline()` and encoding via the string syntax. Thanks for the help.